# iOS Application development Certification

Tags: ios, development

As we all know about the Microsoft Certified Professional Programs. I need to ask is there any institute offering online certification for iOS Professional Developer. I have visited [Standford University](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/), as it is offering a course but I could not get it that is it like MCP or not?